# WhatsApp Link Preview Images different dimensions depending on sender device

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, whatsapp, meta-tags

A webpage I am currently working on needs to have preview images when sending a link through WhatsApp. That by itself is not an issue, as I am following the [OG Protocol specified here](https://ogp.me/). The issue is that depending on which device the link is sent from, the images are displayed differently. Here are a few examples:

[**WhatsApp Desktop on MacOS Ventura 13.1**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okmx8.png)

[**WhatsApp Web (Chrome 108.0.5359.124) and WhatsApp on Android**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsGmF.png)

[**WhatsApp on IOS**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO5bR.png)

(For some reason, this time it decided to take the Favicon instead of the specified image.)

Here are the relevant Meta-Tags from the Page <head>

```html
<meta name="description" content="Wir treten mit Regierungsrätin Jacqueline Fehr und Nationalrätin Priska Seiler Graf zu den Regierungsratswahlen an – ein hochkarätiges Duo mit langjähriger Erfahrung und ausgewiesener Kompetenz.">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://wahlen-kanton-zuerich.ch/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/SPZH-KR-Wahlen23-RR-Bilder-–-WEB4-Kopie.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1720">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="1200">
<meta property="og:locale" content="de_DE">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Priska Seiler Graf und Jacqueline Fehr in den Regierungsrat!">
<meta property="og:description" content="Wir treten mit Regierungsrätin Jacqueline Fehr und Nationalrätin Priska Seiler Graf zu den Regierungsratswahlen an – ein hochkarätiges Duo mit langjähriger Erfahrung und ausgewiesener Kompetenz.">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://wahlen-kanton-zuerich.ch/regierungsrat/">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Wir ergreifen Partei.">
```

It is baffling to me that the same code would result in different preview Images depending on the sender. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @tripleee Thanks! I just replaced the image with the actual excerpt of the <head>.

Comment: You have 3 screenshots from 3 different clients. Seems reasonable that different client may display it different.

Comment: Not quite, the client they're being displayed on are the same. The client they were *sent from* is different. Funny enough, when *viewing* the same message on different clients, they're being displayed the same. Or are you suggesting that depending on the sender device, it is reasonable to have the messages be rendered differently? Cause that makes no sense to me if I am honest.